# In a connected graph, if the maximum path you could make is of length 100, and there are two paths of length 100, aren't they the same path?

Tags: connectedness, hamiltonian-path

Here's the question:

> Let G be a connected graph. (Remember that this means that every two vertices of G can be joined by
> a path starting at one and ending at the other.)
>
> Suppose also that G has the following property: there is no path of length more than 100 in G. (Remember
> also that the length of path is the number of edges it traverses, which is one less than the number of vertices
> in the path.)
>
> Prove that if P1 and P2 are two paths in G with length exactly 100, then there must be some vertex that
> belongs to both P1 and P2.

Isn't every vertex connected in a connected graph? (ie, the longest path will touch every vertex) In which case the maximum length of the path would be the number of vertices minus 1. Wouldn't that mean that P1 and P2 share a vertex because they share every vertex?

If I'm wrong I guess my question would be "What is example of a graph with a maximum path length in which two paths that are equal to the maximum path length only share one vertex?"

Comment: Think of a star graph (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29) - the longest path has length 2 and this would be any path starting on the outside, going inward, and then going to one of the other outer vertices.  Two such paths need only share the inner vertex.

Comment: Great example, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a path $P_1$ of length $100$; it has $101$ vertices. Let $v$ be the middle vertex, and attach to it two more disjoint paths of length $50$ each. You now have a big X in which each of the four arms is a path of length $50$. This graph has $\binom42=6$ paths of length $100$ and no longer path, and as long as you pick one of the three pairs of maximal paths that share only the vertex $v$, you have two paths of length $100$ with a single vertex in common.

**Added:** For the actual result, suppose that $P_1$ and $P_2$ have no vertex in common. Let $Q$ be a shortest path between some vertex of $P_1$ to some vertex of $P_2$; note that the endpoints of $Q$ are the only vertices that it shares with $P_1\cup P_2$. Show that if $u$ is the endpoint of $Q$ on $P_1$, and $v$ is the endpoint of $Q$ on $P_2$, then there are an endpoint $x$ of $P_1$ and an endpoint $y$ of $P_2$ such that the path from $x$ to $u$ along $P_1$, from $u$ to $v$ along $Q$, and from $v$ to $y$ along $P_2$ has length greater than $100$.

Comment: Your answer combined with the other comment was really helpful, thanks

Comment: @user2963116: You’re welcome.

Comment: Do you have any hints on how to prove this question by the way? I understand the concept now, but I can't seem to word exactly why that would be the case in an adequate proof

Comment: @user2963116: I’ve added an extensive hint.